# Running IBackgroundTask on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, background-task

I have a UAP application, and when I debug on a Windows 10 Phone, IBackgroundTask is triggered automatically. When I debug on Local Machine (Windows 10 x86), it isn't called at all. How can I trigger it?

Comment: Which type of task is it? On which "event" it should be triggered?

Comment: [GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.gattcharacteristicnotificationtrigger.gattcharacteristicnotificationtrigger)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to set a system trigger. In your manifest, you need a "Background Tasks" declaration, with a "System event" property. 
In your C# code, you have to register your task and you can bind the task to a particular event system like "NetworkStateChange" :

```
foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
{
    task.Value.Unregister(true);
}

var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
if (result == BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied)
{
    return;
}

BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "<task name>";
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "<task entry point>";

builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange, false));
var registration = builder.Register();
```

With this code, you can launch the task with a manual manipulation on the network (switch wifi or unplung your cable).

Comment: Hello @t.ouvre , thanks for your answer. My code is similar to yours, but I replaced my SetTrigger with your SystemTrigger line and your code works for  both PC and Mobile. My BackgroundTask only works for mobile. I'm upvoting your answer because it gives me a lead that the issue might be my particular Trigger type

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, you can trigger a background task directly from Visual Studio 2015. There's a drop-down menu called `Lifecycle Events` that lets you invoke `Suspend`, `Resume` and any registered background tasks. Set a breakpoint in your task beforehand. (In my case the class implementing the background task is called `NotifyChanges`.)

[image]

Comment: This isn't working for me for some reason! Using t.ouvre's NetworkStateChanged, the background task is triggered, but [the background task is not listed](http://postimg.org/image/g8q07f7w5/)

Comment: I assume you have the background task listed in the manifest?

Comment: Yes they are:       <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="MyClass.Task">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="systemEvent" />
            (more here)
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>

Comment: The only diff from my own is that mine runs on a timer, e.g., `<Task Type="timer" />`. Apparently you're allowed to add more than one type of triggers to the same background task -- what happens if you try to add a timer trigger?

Comment: I just tried replacing my "timer" trigger with "systemEvent", and my background task still shows up, and can still be triggered. I'm afraid I don't know why you can't see it.

Comment: Actually interestingly when I used a timer trigger instead, my task shows up now.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't gotten me as close to solving my issue as I wanted to. GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger works on mobile,  but not on PC

Comment: Starting to think it's some sort of bug with VS, since the other triggers work (but not the one I need).